# Optimizing Lottie/JSON Images in Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, cdn, lottie

I'm having some issues optimizing the .json Lottie files on my site. On my homepage, I use Wordpress in combination with Elementor Pro, WP Rocket, Bunny CDN, and Asset CleanUp Pro. I've managed to take my site loading speed down from 8 seconds to under 2 seconds; however, my lottie files are the only thing I'm struggling to optimize.

There's one lottie image above the fold that I would like to load immediately, and then I have 8 other lottie images on the page that I'd ideally like to load on user-interaction (scroll/mouse/etc). All the lottie images are anywhere from 50kb to 200kb.

One of the interesting things I've noticed, is that according to GTMetrix, the .json files are not using Keep-Alive even though I have that configured in my htaccess, so that slows down the loading of the .json images even more. I'm not sure why they aren't being enabled by keep-alive.

Another thing I've noticed is that according to GTMetrix, the .json files aren't being served from my CDN.

What I've tried:

- I thought I could use Elementor Pro Lottie's feature to link to the CDN version of my .json files; however, Elementor wasn't able to load anything when I did that. It simply left a blank white space. It only seems to load the files from a media gallery.
- I thought I could use the "delay Javascript execution" feature in WPRocket by linking the .json files below the fold; however, GTMetrix still loaded those files normally on the page load.
- I tried enabling the "lazy load" feature on Elementor's plugin for those .json files - that somewhat worked, but it caused content shifts that messes up the flow of the site too much.

Any ideas how I could speed up/optimize the lottie images here? Ideally, if I could use the Keep-Alive or the CDN version of the Lottie images, or potentially get some kind of delayed user-interaction load that won't make my site shift so much... that would be ideal.

Any help would be appreciated!

[GTMetrix Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7stTm.jpg)

Comment: Hi Ethan did you manage to resolved this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I am also having a very similar issue, would love to hear if any solutions have been found!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free tool [Lottiemizer](https://lottiemizer.com/) that optimizes and shrinks  the Lottie JSON file size.

https://lottiemizer.com/

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: The file sizes here are probably not the issue.  They seem to be small already.  I see `77k` for the first one in their screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement lazy loading, you have to reserve the space for the image ahead of time.  If you images non-responsive, that can be as simple as using a div around them:

```
<div style=height:43px;width:107px>
    <img class=lazy data-lazy=foo.jpg>
</div>
```

If your images are responsive, you need to use a placeholder with the same aspect ratio. https://www.andreaverlicchi.eu/blog/aspect-ratio-modern-reserve-space-lazy-images-async-content-responsive-design/ has new ways of doing that that work in modern browsers.